# Prove that a vector is not a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I just started learning linear algebra and learnt a few axioms, but I do not understand how to show that $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} |3x + 4y - z = 2\}$ is not a subspace. Any help would be great.

Comment: Every subspace needs to contain $0$. Can you finish?

Comment: @Ravi thanks for the tip  :-)  and what i understood is that : for every element $v$  in $V$ there is an element $\prime v\prime$ such that $v + v\prime = 0$. This condition is not true?

Comment: @LuaiGhunim subspaces need to be closed under addition. So the condition you proposed (existence of inverses) couples with closure under addition implies that 0 must be in any subspace.

Comment: You mean to show that the set is not a subspace?

Comment: Is $(0,0,0)$ in the set or not? All subspaces contain the zero vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

”A vector” cannot be a subspace. A subspace, $M$, is a subset of another vector space, V, that follows two rules:

– $M$ is closed under vector addition
– $M$ is closed under scalar multiplication

Now let's see if your set $M={(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 \mid 3x+4y-z=2}$ is closed under vector addition:

Just for formality, I will define a transformation $T: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow M$ such that $T(x,y,z)=3x+4y-z$. Take the vectors $T(x,y,z)=3x+4y-z$ and $T(a,b,c)=3a+4b-c$. Adding these together gives us $T\bigg((x,y,z)+(a,b,c)\bigg)=T(x+a, y+b, z+c)=3(x+a)+4(y+b)-(z+c) = \quad(3x+4y-z)+(3a+4b-c).$

But if we look at our definition for $M$, $(3x+4y-z)=2$ and $(3a+4b-c)=2$. That means that $3(x+a)+4(y+b)-(z+c)=4$ and is therefore not in $M$. Therefore $M$ is not closed under vector addition and is not a subspace.